# Client Error: bad object in message: bson length doesn't match what we found

Tags: django, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, python-requests

I'm having an issue POSTing data to a Node/Express API that leverages Mongoose and MongoDB. When attempting a bulk insert using this schema, data and handler:

```
// Mongoose schema
var NotificationSchema = new Schema({
    uuid: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        index: true
    },
    message: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    url: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

// sample data
[
    {
        'uuid': '34e1ffef49ad4001bb9231c21bdb3be7',
        'url': '/polls/4666386cb92348af93417e9abb9ce880/forecast/',
        'message': '@btaylor has shared a poll with you'
    },
    {
        'uuid': '42d6a9f4b3f5416b952452c26e01789a',
        'url': '/polls/4666386cb92348af93417e9abb9ce880/forecast/',
        'message': '@btaylor has shared a poll with you'
    }
]

// route handler
Notification.prototype.bulkInsert = function(data, callback) {
    NotificationSchema.collection.insert(data, function(error, documents) {
        if (error) { return callback(error, null); }

        if (documents.length == 0) { return callback(null, null); }

        callback(null, documents);
    });
};
```

I get this back when POSTed as `x-www-form-urlencoded` via Postman:

```
{ [MongoError: Client Error: bad object in message: bson length doesn't match what we found]
  name: 'MongoError',
  err: 'Client Error: bad object in message: bson length doesn\'t match what we found',
  code: 10307,
  n: 0,
  connectionId: 125,
  ok: 1 }
```

My Mocha tests posting the same data work just fine. What am I doing wrong?

## [Update]

After further testing, it appears that the body of the request is being improperly parsed when posted from my Django web application using the requests library.

My post is constructed as:

```
requests.post(url, data=data)
```

where `data` is a Python dictionary:

```
{'data': [{'url': '/polls/4666386cb92348af93417e9abb9ce880/forecast/', 'message': '@btaylor has shared a poll with you', 'uuid': '34e1ffef49ad4001bb9231c21bdb3be7'}, {'url': '/polls/4666386cb92348af93417e9abb9ce880/forecast/', 'message': '@btaylor has shared a poll with you', 'uuid': '42d6a9f4b3f5416b952452c26e01789a'}]}
```

The `data` argument that the above route handler receives is populated from `req.body.data`. In my Express middleware, I am using the following body parsers:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

however, logging the request body, as posted from Django/requests results in:

```
[ 'url', 'message', 'uuid', 'url', 'message', 'uuid' ]
```

why are the values being stripped out, along with the curly braces defining the objects? The content type of the post is being reported correctly as:

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Anyone have any ideas? This works perfectly from Postman, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there was one problem on the Python side and one on the Express side.

The list of objects that I was posting from Python needed to be converted to a JSON string before being set in the values posted:

```
# views.py
notifications = json.dumps([{"uuid": profile.uuid_str,
    "message": message, "url": poll_forecast_url}
    for profile in shared_with])

requests.post(url, data={'data': notifications})
```

Earlier in my question you'll notice that I indicated the tests from Postman were failing. That's because the value of `req.body.data` on the Express side was being received as a string when an encoding of `x-www-form-urlencoded` was set in the Postman options. To fix this, I added this line before the `Notification.bulkInsert()` function call:

```
var data = typeof(req.body.data) == 'string' ? JSON.parse(req.body.data) : req.body.data;
```

to properly convert the JSON string to an object before passing it to `.bulkInsert()`